# How to dockerize a meteor fresh application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, meteor, docker-compose

I am trying to dockerize a meteor application (v1.6.1) by building a docker image using `Dockerfile` and creating and running a container using `docker-compose.yml` but all my trials failed.

I have used this command to build a docker meteor image

```
docker build -t badis/meteor .
```

I have a good experience using meteor and little using docker.

Here my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/?release=1.6.1 | sh
RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Here my `.dockerignore`

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

Here my `docker-compose.yml`

```
dashboard:
  image: badis/meteor
  ports:
   - "81:80"
  links:
   - mongo
  environment:
   - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo/boiler
   - ROOT_URL=http://localhost


mongo:
  image: mongo:3.2
```

Comment: and what errors do you obtain? And why do you not want to use [already dockerized meteor apps](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=meteor&starCount=0)?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jeq45  . I am getting this error, it's related to permission inside container

Comment: @BukharovSergey the container start few seconds before it crashes due that error related to user permissions

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite self-explanatory. You need to pass `--allow-superuser` when running the meteor build command.

Comment: I want to fix the error inside Dockerfile. it's possible by creating a new user and switch to it but i don't now how to do it.